# Converting geodetic coordinates to ENU coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, datum, geodesy, ecef

I am trying to understand conversion from geodetic coordinates to ENU coordinates. As per [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion), its two step process: geodetic to ECEF coordinates and then ECEF coordinates to ENU coordinates. Wikipedia gives the conversion from geodetic to ECEF coordinates as follows:

[image]

*a* is equatorial radis (semi-major axis)
*b* is the polar radius (semi-minor axis)
*f*=1-*b*/*a* is the flattening of the ellipsoid

However, I am not satisfied with direct formula. Can someone post the detailed proof of these equations? If not the proofs, the link / source / any resource discussing the same?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am asking single question only: proof of these equations.